# How can I raise an exception down the stack in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, exception

If I have a function `foo_1` that calls `foo_2`, and `foo_2` can raise an exception that I want to handle in `foo_1`. How can I do that?

I want to write something like this, so that I only have to deal with one `begin`/`rescue` block:

```
def foo_1
  begin
    foo_2
  rescue SomeException
    # Do stuff
  end
end

def foo_2
  # Do stuff that can throw SomeException
end
```

How can I pass the exception from `foo_2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a stack frame doesn't a thrown exception, then it will automatically propagate down to the next stack frame, until it's either handled or it reaches the bottom of the stack (at which point the Ruby interpreter handles it by printing it out and your program terminating). You don't have to do anything to enable this behavior.

```
class SomeException < StandardError; end

def foo_1
  begin
    foo_2
  rescue SomeException => e
    "Rescued #{e.message} in foo_1"
  end
end

def foo_2
  foo_3
end

def foo_3
  raise SomeException.new("kaboom!")
end

# > foo_1
# => "Rescued kaboom! in foo_1"
```

Comment: Hmmm... I must be doing something else wrong then since I don't seem to be seeing this behavior. Lemme play around with it a bit more

Comment: Yep, I was just being stupid... Was trying to catch the exception in the wrong function. I should have known. But thanks. Probably would have struggled for a bit longer had you not told me outright that this is how it should work.